# Merge json object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have that kind of json:

```
const a = [{
  value: 5,
  sum: 32,
},
{
  value 6,
  sum: 32,
}]
```

How to get this result:

```
const a = [{
  value1: 5,
  value2: 6,
  sum: 32
}]
```

I know that I have "key" collision. Is it possible to get that result?
Thanks !

Comment: you cannot have multiple properties with the same name in one object

Comment: No, why ever would you need this kind of result?

Comment: i know, but can get for example value1: 5, and value2:6?

Comment: Well, potentially yeah, although it might be rather `value` & `value1` however, the question why would fail me still, maybe there are alternative solutions for whatever you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sure, but that looks, once again, like a terrible idea. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level? Why do you have an array with two different kinds of objects inside in the first place? That is already a smell. This really looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I edited my post, this is exactly, what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could theoretically merge all your props, and maintain an index to create the latest keys at will.

Following snippet would do, but I didn't really test it that thoroughly.

I do fail to see the benefit of this merged data, as it seems that suddenly all context will be lost, how can you know which `sum` is related to which `value`

```js
const a = [{
  value: 5,
  sum: 32,
},
{
  value: 6,
  sum: 32,
},
{
  value: 7,
  sum: 16
},
{
  value: 5,
  sum: 16
}];

function mergeObjectsInArray( array ) {
  const keys = {};
  return [ array.reduce( (current, item) => {
    Object.keys( item ).forEach( key => {
      let target = key;
      if (keys[key]) {
        if (current[key] === item[key]) {
          // same value
          return;
        }
        for (let i = 1; i <= keys[key]; i++) {
          if (current[key+i] === item[key]) {
            // same value in previous iterations
            return;
          }
        }
        target = key + (++keys[key]);
        if (keys[key] === 2) {
          // delete the original key and replace it with key1
          // only needs to happen once
          let temp = current[key];
          delete current[key];
          current[key+'1'] = temp;
        }
        current[target] = item[key];
        return;
      }
      keys[key] = 1;
      current[target] = item[key];
    } );
    return current;
  }, {})];
}

console.log( mergeObjectsInArray( a ) );
```

Comment: Cool, it is almost what i want. if the vale (sum) is the same i don't want to create sum1: and sum2: (only one sum). I want to only extend if the value is different

Comment: @dybleG That is exactly what the code is doing ;) Just I added an extra fields with different sums